# Number of ways to order n objects among r boxes

Tags: combinatorics

How many ways to order $8$ balls among $3$ boxes for which no box is empty 
I know the formula
$$C^{n+r-1}_r$$
If I sub $n=8$ and $r=3$ the result is the number of ways of ordering the $8$ ball among $3$ boxes but without any restrictions so how can i satisfy the condition of the problem ?

Comment: If you have three balls and eight boxes, and each ball can only go into one box at a time... you will have at least five empty boxes.  You can't have no box empty, so there are zero ways.  You need at least as many balls as there are boxes to be able to satisfy that condition.

Comment: Once you correct your problem into something more useful, the [twelve-fold way](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twelvefold_way) should be able to answer your question.

Comment: This is never possible because of the pigeonhole principle.  It is clearly visible that 3 balls cannot be ordered in 8 boxes without leaving any box empty.  Hence the answer is 0.

Comment: Sorry , i have edited it please review it @JMoravitz

Comment: You have edited the question,but if there are 8 balls and 3 boxes, the formula you are quoting is wrong. Read up "stars and bars" combinatorics or go through dozens of similar problems on this site. (Btw, I am assuming that the balls are identical,and the boxes distinct, but the full details need to be specified in the problem)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You have at least one ball in each box, so lets consider that you have 5 balls and you can put them in 3 boxes as you want. You do this using combinations, $\binom {3} {5}$.

Comment: I am afraid your solution is incorrect. Please search "stars and bars" on this site which has many problems of this kind.